# How to use Glue to remove ''(single quote) in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift, whitespace, aws-glue

[image: Table]

When I upload table from `S3` to `AWS redshift` by using `Glue`, the table that shows on Redshift including single quote('') in the table.

I think it is the white space in the original table. Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the input file? Are you sure it is a double-quote (`"`) and not two single-quotes (`''`)?

Comment: There are blanks in my input file and when I clicked in that blank, it showed a single space bar inside. I think the delimiter looks this space bar inside the blank as sting and it covers that sting with quote('').

Comment: 2011-03-31,CONV-FI, , ,PURC, , , , , ,E, , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,29440801572, , , ,1900-01-01, , ,1900-01-01, , , , , , , ,X, , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,0, , , , , , , , ,1900-01-01,00:00:00, ,1900-01-01, , , , ,0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,0, , ,2020-01-31 03:31:02.185 UTC

Comment: My input file(.txt) look like this. I use AWS Glue to upload it to Redshift and even I coverted it to .csv(UTF-8). It showed the same result.